# How to disable the default gdm login screen

Tags: debian, gnome, gdm, gdm3

I'd like my Debian 10 box with vanilla GNOME to prompt for login at a tty/text terminal instead of having the gdm GUI pop up by default. Is there a way to change some config such that it works like this, and then the GNOME interface can be started manually with e.g. `startx`?

Comment: Well I think you want to use `multi-user.target`  target. Systemd uses targets where Sysv / init  system uses `runlevels`. So basically what you need to do is. 1) Check your current target using `systemctl get-default`. This will most probably return `graphical.target`. Now you can change this by running `systemctl set-default multi-user.target` && reboot. I forgot to mention that you can run `systemctl isolate multi-user.target` to force an immediate switch to the textual interface

Comment: This should be an answer, worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Well I think you want to use multi-user.target target. Systemd uses targets where Sysv / init system uses runlevels. So basically what you need to do is. 1) Check your current target using

```
systemctl get-default
```

This will most probably return graphical.target. Now you can change this by running

```
systemctl set-default multi-user.target && reboot
```

Or, without the need to reboot your system, you'd run

```
systemctl isolate multi-user.target
```

to force an immediate switch to the textual interface